# Need Help in Integrating Javascript with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have wordpress account for blogging. Recently I have opted for PopUpAds. I have the javascript code with me which I received from PopUpAds.

Can any one please tell me how to integrate this code into wordpress??

Any informative links will also be very helpful.

Thank You In advance.

Comment: PS: I am new to coding. Kindly let me know where can I get the access to Wordpress code so that I can insert this javascript.

Comment: you need to edit the parts of files in which you want to add code something like post.php or where you would like to insert the code starts with <script> end with </script>

Answer (score 0):

It might be the safest ( but not the best ) way to install the plugin which allows you to add inline javascript code. 
I.e. something like this - https://wordpress.org/plugins/tc-custom-javascript/

Also, if you can edit functions.php file within your active theme, the quickest way is to add a patch of code there:

```
<?php //add opening php tag only if there is closing tag at the end of functions.php file 
function pop_up_ads_script() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 //your script from PopUpAds goes here 
 //check if PopUpAds code includes also script tags, then avoid adding duplicate tags
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'pop_up_ads_script' );
```

For this approach, be careful when editing and saving functions.php, since you might cause error due to bad syntax or typo, so first check if php tags. I
would suggest to do this via FTP access, rather  than through built-in WordPress file editor.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Wordpress plugin that lets you insert arbitrary HTML code as a shortcode is the best way to go IMO. That way the external code doesn't mess with the wysiwyg editor. I use this plugin: https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/

If the JavaScript code should be added to the head section of your page, there are plugins that do that as well.

Check out this useful blog post for adding external JS and CSS to Wordpress: http://blog.dynamicdrive.com/add-custom-javascript-css-wordpress/